# Combine Data of Two Rows in One Column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

**Query:**

```
SELECT *
   FROM MYTABLE
   WHERE
   (custom_date BETWEEN '16-MAR-15'
   AND '15-APR-15'))
pivot(SUM(user_value) FOR custom_date IN(to_date('16/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day16,   to_date('17/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day17,   to_date('18/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day18,   to_date('19/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day19,   to_date('20/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day20,   to_date('21/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day21,   to_date('22/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day22,   to_date('23/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day23,   to_date('24/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day24,   to_date('25/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day25,   to_date('26/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day26,   to_date('27/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day27,   to_date('28/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day28,   to_date('29/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day29,   to_date('30/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day30,   to_date('31/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day31,   to_date('01/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day01,   to_date('02/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day02,   to_date('03/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day03,   to_date('04/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day04,   to_date('05/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day05,   to_date('06/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day06,   to_date('07/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day07,   to_date('08/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day08,   to_date('09/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day09,   to_date('10/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day10,   to_date('11/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day11,   to_date('12/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day12,   to_date('13/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day13,   to_date('14/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day14,   to_date('15/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day15))
ORDER BY username;
```

Query outputs data for two months `Mar-Apr 2015` as shown in image. The first row is for month `Mar-15` and second for `Apr-15`.

[image]

As seen in the image, `DAY 29, DAY 30, DAY 31` has value`8` filled up for `Mar-15` and `null` for `Apr-15`.

For `Apr-15`, `DAY 01, DAY 02, DAY 03` has value `8` while `null` for ``Mar-15`.

How to combine data for both `Mar-Apr 2015` in order to show like below

[image: Updated]

Comment: Can you really do a pivot in mysql?

Comment: The query is actually being executed on oracle db usign PIVOT.

Comment: `custom_date BETWEEN '16-MAR-15'
   AND '15-APR-15'` Not directly relevant, but why are you using **string**? `'16-MAR-15'` is a string and **NOT** a **DATE**.

Comment: What additional columns are selected? If you use PIVOT function then result is grouped by all other columns you have in your select (in your case all except `custom_date` and `user_value`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this query:

```
`SELECT sum(day16 ) as day16 ,
sum(day17 ) as day17 ,
sum(day18 ) as day18 ,
sum(day19 ) as day19 ,
sum(day20 ) as day20 ,
sum(day21 ) as day21 ,
sum(day22 ) as day22 ,
sum(day23 ) as day23 ,
sum(day24 ) as day24 ,
sum(day25 ) as day25 ,
sum(day26 ) as day26 ,
sum(day27 ) as day27 ,
sum(day28 ) as day28 ,
sum(day29 ) as day29 ,
sum(day30 ) as day30 ,
sum(day31 ) as day31 ,
sum(day01 ) as day01 ,
sum(day02 ) as day02 ,
sum(day03 ) as day03 ,
sum(day04 ) as day04 ,
sum(day05 ) as day05 ,
sum(day06 ) as day06 ,
sum(day07 ) as day07 ,
sum(day08 ) as day08 ,
sum(day09 ) as day09 ,
sum(day10 ) as day10 ,
sum(day11 ) as day11 ,
sum(day12 ) as day12 ,
sum(day13 ) as day13 ,
sum(day14 ) as day14 ,
sum(day15 ) as day15 ,
username
   FROM MYTABLE
   WHERE
   (custom_date BETWEEN '16-MAR-15'
   AND '15-APR-15'))
pivot(SUM(user_value) FOR custom_date IN(to_date('16/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day16,   to_date('17/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day17,   to_date('18/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day18,   to_date('19/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day19,   to_date('20/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day20,   to_date('21/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day21,   to_date('22/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day22,   to_date('23/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day23,   to_date('24/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day24,   to_date('25/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day25,   to_date('26/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day26,   to_date('27/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day27,   to_date('28/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day28,   to_date('29/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day29,   to_date('30/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day30,   to_date('31/03/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day31,   to_date('01/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day01,   to_date('02/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day02,   to_date('03/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day03,   to_date('04/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day04,   to_date('05/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day05,   to_date('06/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day06,   to_date('07/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day07,   to_date('08/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day08,   to_date('09/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day09,   to_date('10/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day10,   to_date('11/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day11,   to_date('12/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day12,   to_date('13/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day13,   to_date('14/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day14,   to_date('15/04/2015',   'DD/MM/YYYY') AS
day15))
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY username;`
```

This will sum all you rows into one.